# Javascript - Accessing another HTML file with window.open();

Tags: javascript, html

So basically what I am trying to do is open a window with a local file location (assumed to be in the same directory), and store the body text of that HTML file as a string into the HTML page running the JavaScript, and then close the new window, as if it were never actually opened, so that all it's used for is its text.
The JavaScript is loaded with the body.

```
function test(){
    var x = document.getElementById("fill");
    var w = window.open('../HTML/HtmlPlaceholder.html');
    var cont = w.document.body.textContent;
    x.innerHTML = cont;
}
```

but when this happens nothing is actually entered into x (the element with the id of "fill").
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: if you do `console.log(cont)` what does the console show you?

Answer (score 1):

`window.open` opens another window which has its own thread and events,

you have two options

**-   Either wait for some time to check the contents**

try this

```
function test(){
    var x = document.getElementById("fill");
    var w = window.open('../HTML/HtmlPlaceholder.html');
    setTimeout( function(){

      var cont = w.document.body.textContent;
      x.innerHTML = cont;

      console.log (cont);
    }, 2000);
}
```

**-  or use the window.onload event of the popup itself**

inside `HtmlPlaceholder.html` put

```
window.onload = function(){

  var x = window.opener.document.getElementById( "fill" );
  x.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
};
```

Comment: Since this is for an assignment and the HTML file name is given to us but is not accessible to edit, I can only go with the first option, which worked fine. But how do I close the opened window after the contents have been checked and stored into the current page?

Comment: @Sean `x.close()` will do it, `x` is the handle to the opened child window

Comment: Worked great thank you, one last thing, do you think 2000 would be the lowest you'd set the delay if you had no idea how big to content of the body is? Just asking because taking that long feels kind of clunky, but it's fine.

Comment: @Sean ideally I would use the second options because I won't know how long it takes to load the pop-up window due to html size or network speed. You need to take a call based on how long it takes to load this window and choose a safe option. You can perhaps show a loading icon to indicate the user that processing is happening